# 3 condition formula in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I need these conditions:

1. If b<=0, a>=0 = a/2
2. if b<=0, a<=0 = 0
3. if b<=0 = 0

I use these 2 formulas:

- =IF(E1<=0,D1/2,IF(E1>=0,"",IF(D1<=0,"")))
- =IF(E1<=0&D1>=0,D1/2,0),elseif(E1<=0&D1<=0,0),IFelse(E1>=0,0)

But when `b<=0`, `a<=0` is not working. *Ex.*- if both `b` and `a` cells are negative or `<=0` it is not working. Is it possible for those 3 conditions apply?

I have tried these formulas, but none of them work correctly when no2 condition:

```
=IF($E$30<=0,$D$26/2,IF($E$30>=0,"",IF(D26<=0,"")))
=IF(E30<=0&D26>=0,D26/2,0),elseif(E30<=0&D26<=0,0),elseif(E30>=0,0)
=IF(E30<=0,D26/2,IF(AND(D26>=0,E30<=0),D26/2,0))
=IF(E30<=0&D26<=0,0),IF(E30<=0&D26>=0,D26/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This by chance what you are after:

```
=IF(AND(B1<=0,A1>=0),A1/2,IF(AND(B1<=0,A1<=0),0,IF(B1<=0,0,"")))
```

Comment: Excactly correct formula. Thanks a lot of Mr #Alan Waage. But If result is "0", is it possible to hide this row automatic by using formula?

Comment: Row hiding is VBA land.  Since you control with the formula when it shows zero, you can just do "" instead.  That won't hide the row, but will supress the zero from showing.